# HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, github, jupyter-notebook, urllib

```py
import urllib.request

def get_site_html(url):
    source = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    return source
```

I am trying to create this function but it throws me the below `error--
HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found`

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import urllib.request

req = urllib.request.Request('your link here')
with urllib.request.urlopen(req) as response:
   the_page = response.read()
```

source: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html

Answer (score 2):

```
import urllib.request
requ = urllib.request.Request(url='')
with urllib.request.urlopen(requ) as f:
data = f.read()
```

try this otherwise you might need a .decode statement along with the .read